# Positioning of a (newly defined) symbol *relative* to a textbox

Tags: tikz-pgf

I defined a set of chevrons with tikz (see below) and would like to be able to
put them at the boundary of a rectangle (text box). As you can see, the code
below does this, but with absolute positioning of the chevrons. I don't mind
working with `xshift` and `yshift`, but -- ideally -- *relative* to the
textbox's, say, upper left corner. How can this be done? Since I have several
chevrons it would be good if the solution allowed to define them as a command
which is invoked once the chevrons are used; but that's not so important.

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=east] at (current page.east)[rectangle, fill, inner sep=6mm, color=gray!20]{% text box
    \color{red}\LARGE Some text here
  };%
  \foreach \x in {0, 3.8} \fill[color=blue, xshift=112mm, yshift=-92mm,
  scale=0.04](0+\x,0)--(2+\x,0)--(4.7+\x,3.8)--(2+\x,7.6)--(0+\x,7.6)--(2.7+\x,3.8)--(0+\x,0);% chevrons
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by invoking them as a command once they are used? If you use them first, why would you want to invoke them again and what purpose would that serve exactly?

Comment: I agree with cfr: it is not really clear what you are trying to do. Can you please expand on your explanation and possibly add an image to show what effect you are after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility although, as I say, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. It allows you to specify the colour and scale of the chevrons as well as demonstrating how to use anchors to place them relative to the text box. You will need to adjust it to taste.

[image: chevron pics]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    pics/my chevron/.style n args={2}{
      code={
        \foreach \x in {0,3.8}
        \path [fill=#1, scale=#2, xshift=\x, pic actions]
          (0+\x,0)--(2+\x,0)--(4.7+\x,3.8)--(2+\x,7.6)--(0+\x,7.6)--(2.7+\x,3.8)--(0+\x,0);
      }
    },
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (my node) [anchor=east] at (current page.east)[rectangle, fill, inner sep=6mm, color=gray!20]{% text box
    \color{red}\LARGE Some text here
  };
  \pic at (my node.north west) {my chevron={blue}{.04}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Update

If you want fixed colour but to adjust the scale, you can use the simpler definition of a `pic`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    my chevron/.pic={
      \foreach \x in {0,3.8}
      \path [fill=blue, scale=#1, xshift=\x, pic actions]
        (0+\x,0)--(2+\x,0)--(4.7+\x,3.8)--(2+\x,7.6)--(0+\x,7.6)--(2.7+\x,3.8)--(0+\x,0);
    },
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (my node) [anchor=east] at (current page.east)[rectangle, fill, inner sep=6mm, color=gray!20]{% text box
    \color{red}\LARGE Some text here
  };
  \pic at (my node.north west) {my chevron={.04}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[Output is identical.]

Note that you can combine Harish Kumar's `shift` with the `pic` here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    my chevron/.pic={
      \foreach \x in {0,3.8}
      \path [fill=blue, scale=#1, xshift=\x, pic actions]
        (0+\x,0)--(2+\x,0)--(4.7+\x,3.8)--(2+\x,7.6)--(0+\x,7.6)--(2.7+\x,3.8)--(0+\x,0);
    },
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node (my node) [anchor=east] at (current page.east)[rectangle, fill, inner sep=6mm, color=gray!20]{% text box
    \color{red}\LARGE Some text here
  };
  \pic [shift={(10pt,10pt)}] at (my node.north west) {my chevron={.04}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously you probably wouldn't want a chevron wandering off like that, but it demonstrates the idea:

[image: wandering chevron]

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I like the idea with the arguments, but I would only need one (not two). I substituted the color into `#1` and made the `#2` a `#1` (and of course removed the `{blue}` and replaced `{2}` by `{1}`), but suddenly the chevrons disappear. Do you know why?

Comment: @MariusHofert So you want the argument for the scale? But the colour fixed?

Comment: .. yes. I just experimented a bit and it turns out that when I choose the scale any smaller than 1, the chevrons disappear and for scale >= 1, they appear (but are huge of course).

Comment: @MariusHofert See my update. I get identical output with this code as I did with the earlier version.

Comment: @MariusHofert See also note at end re. combining the `shift` option harish kumar demonstrated with my definition of the pic.